# I want to use this shell script and change it to using command line argument

Tags: linux, ubuntu

using ubuntu terminal so it could be with command-lins arg.
thank you.

```
echo "enter number"
read num
function prime
{
for((i=2; i<=num/2; i++))
do
  if [ $((num%i)) -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "$num is not a prime number."
    exit
  fi
done
echo "$num is a prime number."
}
r=`prime $number`
echo "$r"
```

Answer (score 0):

2nd line can look like this

```
num=$1
```

function should be define first before other code

Comment: The spaces around the equals sign are a syntax error.

Comment: sorry too much python
num=$1